# Global css rules in ionic 2 does not work

Tags: sass, ionic2

I'm trying to declare some basic css rules to use them globally in my app. Like pull-rx, pull-lx and so on...

After writing these rules into app.scss, the main.css file inside the build folder gets updated correctly, but when it comes to use one of these rules inside a "LoginPage" for example, each of the rules I've declared before are ignored. Am I missing something?

If I write the pull-rx class inside the login.scss file instead, it will work. Is there a way to get a class globally?

## app.scss:

```
.pull-rx {
    float: right !important
}

.pull-lx{
    float: left !important
}
```

## app.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule, ErrorHandler } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicModule, IonicErrorHandler } from 'ionic-angular';
import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
import { LoginPage } from '../pages/login/login';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
    LoginPage,
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
    LoginPage,
  ],
  providers: [{ provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler }]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

## login.html:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>
      Astrid <small><i>Beta</i></small> <span class="pull-rx">Login</span>
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>


<ion-content padding>

</ion-content>
```

Comment: That is odd. Your code looks correct. I tried to reproduce in my code and it is working as expected. Are you sure your `app.scss` is being included in the build?

Comment: Hi @Matt! Thanks for answering, yes the build gets the classes into its main.css, and yeah that's really odd. I'll try again later this night though, maybe I'm missing something stupid -.-''

Comment: There is one thing I see. Your login markup is displayed under the `login.ts` title. I am assuming this is a typo.

Comment: Yeah sorry it's a typo

Answer (score 1):

I've figured this out. Since Ionic uses scsss as preprocessor, I have to set the semicolons ";" at the end of the rule. Since I am used to code in sass that were causing the problem.